# Exiting a '&pattern' search in less

Tags: search, less

After using a search in `less` of the format `&pattern`, which displays only matching lines, how can I go back to displaying all lines in the file?

<kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't do anything as far as I can tell. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> doesn't either. <kbd>q</kbd> simply exits `less`.

Comment: `&` with an empty pattern should work. What version of `less` do you have? Have you checked `man less`?

Comment: I was using the built-in help for less, and now I see how easily I could've found it in the man page. Lesson learned. Version 436.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just enter & again with no search term

Comment: Does not work if the previous search didn't return any lines.

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico I think it works but you're left at the end of the file. You can e.g. hit 'Home' to see the lines.